# Using Nexys 4 audio port

Tags: fpga, audio, board

I have a digilent Nexys 4 board that I am using for learning Verilog. I have written a code that requires connecting an audio speaker to the board for evaluating. What is the speaker that can be used for Nexys 4 board?
Nexys 4 manual: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~montek/teaching/Comp541-Fall14/Lab/Nexys4.pdf

Comment: So this question is merely "Where can I buy a speaker to test with my board?"

Comment: "What are my sources for obtaining one" is another way of saying "where" yes? You want the name of a supplier or shop that will sell you something?

Comment: can you link us to the Nexys 4 board's manual/schematics? What "ohm" speaker is it designed to drive? If it has a standard audio jack, go to a dodgy asian shop and buy one and plug it in and see if it works..

Answer (score 1):

From the schematics, it looks like it is driven directly from a FPGA digital out pin (presumably via PWM) through some op-amps to form an active filter for reconstruction. It doesn't look like you can hook up a passive speaker directly, I would just try getting some amplified "multimedia speakers" such as the USB powered ones that come with desktop computers.